# EXT4 journal=data and mmap

Tags: filesystems, ext4, mmap, journaling

Does enabling `data=journal` for ext4 make any difference when using `mmap()` to update a file?

The ext4 man page says:

> journal
> All data is committed into the journal prior to being written into the main filesystem.

Which isn't really helpful in saying when the data is actually written to the file system.

I would imagine that for memory-mapped files, the writes that I perform between two `msync()` calls are not going to be atomic. Some writes might be durable before others and result in an inconsistent state.

Does this mean `data=journal` is only useful for the read/write interface and with mmap I should always use a write-ahead-log?